# Excel VBA instantiate AfterCalculate event handler when opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

I want to handle Excel's [Application.AfterCalculate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.aftercalculate).

It appears that this can only be done using a class.  How do I define and instantiate such an event handler when the workbook is opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following code in the `ThisWorkbook` object.

```
Public WithEvents appEventHandler As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set appEventHandler = Application
End Sub

Private Sub appEventHandler_AfterCalculate()
    ' DO WHATEVER YOU WANT After Calculate.  E.g., call a Public Subroutine.
    MsgBox "AfterCalculate called"
End Sub
```

If the AfterCalculate handler modifies anything in the spreadsheet then, in order to prevent unexpected repeated or recursive callbacks, I wrap it in an `If` statement to make sure it only runs once, as in the following Module code:

```
Public RunningAfterCalculate As Boolean

Public Sub RunAfterCalculate()
    If Not RunningAfterCalculate Then
        RunningAfterCalculate = True
        ' DO WHATEVER YOU WANT AfterCalculate
        ' ...
        RunningAfterCalculate = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that if for some reason VBA encounters an unhandled exception you will have to reset the `appEventHandler` – e.g. by running a sub like this:

```
Public Sub RestartEventHandler()
    Set ThisWorkbook.appEventHandler = Application
    Application.EnableEvents = True  ' Just in case...
    RunningAfterCalculate = False
End Sub
```